# How to generate html version of Isabelle theory

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I have an Isabelle theory file, called `John.thy`. I would like to show it to my friend, but my friend doesn't have Isabelle, and the raw `.thy` files aren't very easy to read. I have seen some web-pages in the Isabelle library (like this one: http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/Finite_Set.html) that have pretty syntax highlighting, and I would like my theory to look like that.

So how can I make `John.html`? I have looked at the documentation and it all looks rather scary and difficult, what with all the build files and make files and the like. Could some kind soul explain the simplest way to do this?

Comment: maybe you could also change the capitalization to `John.thy` and `John.html` in your post (to make the convention apparent for future readers). Then I could drop my comment about it from my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the answer to your question (see also the [Isabelle System Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf), Section 3.2 - *System build options*):

To generate HTML for your `John.thy`, create a file named `ROOT`, in the same directory as `John.thy`, with the following contents

```
session John = "HOL" +
  theories
    John
```

and then, staying in that same directory, invoke

```
isabelle build -d . -o browser_info -v John
```

where

- `-d .` specifies that the current directory should be searched for sessions (which are specified in a `ROOT` file)
- `-o browser_info` is the essential flag to generate HTML (a.k.a. *browser info*), and
- `-v` (the *verbose* flag) is useful to see in which directory the result is put

The above invocation will output something similar to

```
Started at Thu Jul 25 09:38:20 JST 2013 [...]
[...]
Session Pure
Session HOL (main)
Session John
Running John ...
John: theory John
[...]
Browser info at /home/username/.isabelle/Isabelle2013/browser_info/HOL/John
[...]
```

(where `[...]` indicates omitted output). So here you see which directory you have to consult to obtain the HTML files.

Having said this, for at least the following reasons I personally prefer PDF over HTML:

- with `-o browser_info` you get a bunch of files in a directory (instead of just a single self-contained file when using `-o document=pdf`)
- not all Isabelle symbols are nicely rendered in HTML (whereas you have full control over symbols when generating PDFs)

**Note:** If you're using the *Isabelle* application for Mac OS, you may need to replace `isabelle` above with `/Applications/Isabelle2013.app/Isabelle/bin/isabelle` or add `/Applications/Isabelle2013.app/Isabelle/bin/` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks Chris. I've taken the liberty of clarifying in which directory one needs to be at each step of the process, since this is something that has confused me before. I found that I needed the full path to Isabelle on my machine, so I also added a note about that.

Comment: You mention that it is convention that theory names start with uppercase letters. The same holds for session names.